Laravel - Symlink Issue with image display in production but works correctly in development environment
I'm encountering a problem with displaying images on my Laravel / Livewire website when I deploy it to production. Strangely, the images are correctly saved, via symlink,  in the storage folder, but they fail to display properly when I try to load them on my pages. This issue only occurs in the production environment, and only for the images saved in the storage folder, while everything works fine in the development environment.
Here's the code I'm using to save and display the images:
The method to Upload in the storage :
    public function uploadImage(){
       

        $this->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048',
             // valida che il file sia un'immagine e abbia una dimensione massima di 2MB
        ]);

        // Verifica se la directory di destinazione esiste, altrimenti creala
        $societaId = Auth::user()->societa_id;
        $storageDirectory = 'public/immagini_associato/associazione_' . $societaId;

        if (!Storage::exists($storageDirectory)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($storageDirectory, 0755, true); // crea la directory 
        }
        // Genera un nome univoco per l'immagine
        $imageName = 'immagine_associato_' . $this->associato->id . '.' . $this->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        
        // Salva l'immagine nello storage
        $this->image->storeAs($storageDirectory, $imageName);
        $this->alert('success', 'Immagine caricata correttamente');
        $this->emit('refreshComponent');
    }

This is the Method to show the Image, on Mount:
    public function mount()
    {
        // Verifica se esiste un'immagine per l'associato
        $societaId = Auth::user()->societa_id;
        $imageName = 'immagine_associato_' . $this->associato->imagePath ; 
        $directory = 'immagini_associato/associazione_' . $societaId;
        
        // Verifica se l'immagine esiste nello storage pubblico
        if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($directory . '/' . $imageName)) {
            $this->imagePath = asset('storage/' . $directory . '/' . $imageName);
        } else {
           
            // Utilizza un'immagine di default se l'immagine non esiste
            $this->imagePath = asset('assets/img/avatars/avatarUnknown.jpg');
        }

    }

I have to say that I can see this image:
$this->imagePath = asset('assets/img/avatars/avatarUnknown.jpg');

But this doesn't work (only in Production)
$this->imagePath = asset('storage/' . $directory . '/' . $imageName);

In my development environment, everything works as expected, but when I deploy to production and try to access the images in the browser, I get a 404 error.
The URL I have in Production is:
src="https://myPortal.com/storage/immagini_associato/associazione_18/immagine_associato_15.png"
And the file does exist in that directory
What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!
This should provide a comprehensive overview of my issue, including the use of symlinks for accessing the storage directory.

did you run php artisan storage:link in production to create the symlink ?

Yes, I did used PHP artisan storage:link in production. And created the symlink correctley

I added Request method then $this.
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048',
    ]);

    $societaId = Auth::user()->societa_id;
    $storageDirectory = 'public/immagini_associato/associazione_' . $societaId;

    if (!Storage::exists($storageDirectory)) {
        Storage::makeDirectory($storageDirectory, 0755, true);
    }

    // Generate a unique name for the image
    $imageName = 'immagine_associato_' . $this->associato->id . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->image->storeAs($storageDirectory, $imageName);

    $this->alert('success', 'Immagine caricata correttamente');
    $this->emit('refreshComponent');
}

In Mount there is extra dot (.) after $this->associato->imagePath
public function mount()
{
    $societaId = Auth::user()->societa_id;
    $imageName = 'immagine_associato_' . $this->associato->id; // Remove the concatenation with $this->associato->imagePath
    $directory = 'immagini_associato/associazione_' . $societaId;

    if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($directory . '/' . $imageName)) {
        $this->imagePath = asset('storage/' . $directory . '/' . $imageName);
    } else {
        $this->imagePath = asset('assets/img/avatars/avatarUnknown.jpg');
    }
}

And clear cache.

Thank you. I have to apologise for the extra dot in Mount. I put it when I created the question here. That doesn't exist in my code.
